# Context Menu for Text

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create context menu for this Text:

```
Text chartSubtitle = new Text("Some text");
```

I general with right-mouse click I want to create menu with Menu item "Select Text" which sends the the text into Windows clip board so I can use the text in other applications.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this tutorial for the basic code on how to set up and write a context menu (it's a bit involved):

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/menu_controls.htm

But, as for the other part: the actual action of adding the text to the clipboard, something like this can work:

```
    final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
    final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putString("Some text");
    clipboard.setContent(content);
```

UPDATE:

To create a Context Menu (from the above cited link - see Example 22-9 near the bottom of the page), you can adapt it to something like this:

```
//Example 22-9 Defining a Context Menu

final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem cmItem1 = new MenuItem("Some Text");
cmItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString("Text from some location");
        clipboard.setContent(content);
    }
});

cm.getItems().add(cmItem1);
pic.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)  
                //handle the right-click (i.e. a context menu)
                //user implemented - so this is entirely up to you
        }
});
```

REFERENCE:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/PutstringvaluetoSystemClipboard.htm

Comment: How I can create context menu for Text?

Comment: @user1285928: Updated. Note: you have to figure out how to handle the right click - in other words, how you select the text. There are a number of ways to do this: one way would be to assign the contents of the `TextField` object to the content. But, that's up to you.

Comment: I want to add Context Menu to Text not TextField.

Comment: @user1285928: That's OK. Just create a `Text` Object instead - the same concept works for both. ;)

Comment: There is no setContextMenu() for Text. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @user1285928: You're correct. My apologies! I really meant: `TextArea`. That has a`setContextMenu`. ;)